# MultiStorage in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have run the below pig script in the grunt shell

```
Register D:\Pig\contrib\piggybank\java\piggybank.jar;

a = load '/part' using PigStorage(',') as (uuid:chararray,timestamp:chararray,Name:chararray,EmailID:chararray,CompanyName:chararray,Location:chararray);

store a  into '/output/multistorage' USING MultiStorage('/output/multistorage','2', 'none', ',');
```

while running this it throws error as shown below

```
2015-11-03 05:47:36,328 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 10
70: Could not resolve MultiStorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.
builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not import your function as the log claims. If the jar is actually accessible for you, you can try the following code (There was one missing line):

```
REGISTER D:\Pig\contrib\piggybank\java\piggybank.jar; 
DEFINE MULTISTORAGE org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage(); 
a = LOAD'/part' USING PigStorage(',') AS (uuid:chararray,timestamp:chararray,Name:chararray,EmailID:chararray,CompanyName:chararray,Location:chararray); 
STORE a  into '/output/multistorage' USING MULTISTORAGE('/output/multistorage','2', 'none', ',');
```

You are then partitionnig by Name.