# MultiStorage file content in pig again

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

Reviewed [MultiStorage in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497182/multistorage-in-pig) and it is similar to this question.

I want to write tuple files(file_path, file_content) to different directory.

Tried class MultiStorage but it wrote whole fields as file contents. Only need to store file_content into directory file_path's parent directory. When I checked the result, there were few lines of field file_content but not the whole contents.

Could anyone help me?